# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'. in Laravel + Webpack

Tags: webpack, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 + webpack. while run the webpack, it's trigger the error.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' in 3.
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

In CSS pre-possessor error.

```
Node 6.3
Npm 3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Laravel-Mix support greaterthan 6.9 version.

update the node version and try it. it's solved.